# How can i apply left outer join conditions on four tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

i was trying to apply joins on 4 tables. but i could not find proper result for that.
i have 4 tables like 1.students,2.college,3.locations,4.departments. so i have same column sid in all tables which can be used to join conditions.
i want all matched rows from four tables as mentioned columns in select statement below and unmatched rows in left table which is left outer join work.

i have tried this syntax.

```
select 
  students.sname,
  college.cname,
  locations.loc,
  department.dept 
from students, college, locaions, departments 
where student.sid=college.sid(+) 
and college.sid=locations.sid(+) 
and locations.sid=department.sid(+);
```

is this right ?

Comment: What does a `sid` represent? Not a student ID, I am sure, as a student doesn't have locations or departments. Is the `sid` unique in one of the four tables?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I was about to tag Oracle, too :-) But then I thought maybe the OP doesn't use Oracle, but only got the syntax from the Internet. Hence my answer that this syntax is Oracle-only.

Comment: I think you may need a full outer join here, as there can be students w/out colleges and colleges w/out students.

Comment: @access_granted . . . Interesting.  I consider a student (well, a *college* student) to necessarily be enrolled in a college (or equivalent).  Similarly, I struggle to think of an educational-institution "college" that has no students (not the Electoral College, of course).

Comment: Well, a dropout, for instance, or someone still applying. It might look cleaner to call everyone a student, than introduce 2 entities (people and students). As for the college with no students - check out https://www.southharmoninstituteoftechnology.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old-fashioned way of outer-joining in an **Oracle** database. For Oracle this statement is correct; in other DBMS it is invalid.

Anyway, nowadays (as of Oracle 9i; in other DBMS much longer) you should use standard SQL joins instead.

```
select 
  s.sname,
  c.cname,
  l.loc,
  d.dept 
from students s
left outer join college c on c.sid = s.sid
left outer join locations l on l.sid = c.sid
left outer join departments d on d.sid = l.sid;
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting this answer. But read Bob's answer, too. He has a point there. The `sid` thing does look dubious, as I already wrote in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Given what you've shown it would appear that what you really want is

```
select s.sname,
       c.cname,
       l.loc,
       d.dept 
from students s
LEFT OUTER JOIN college c
  ON c.SID = s.SID
LEFT OUTER JOIN locations l
  ON l.SID = s.SID
LEFT OUTER JOIN departments d 
  ON d.SID = s.SID
```

The issue in your original query is that because an OUTER JOIN is an optional join, you can end up with NULL values being returned in one of the join fields, which then prevents any of the downstream values being joined. I agree with @ThorstenKettner who observes in a comment that SID is apparently a "student ID", but it's not reasonable or appropriate to have a "student ID" field on tables named COLLEGE, LOCATIONS, or DEPARTMENTS. Perhaps you need to update your design to allow any number of students to be associated with one of these entities, perhaps using a "join" table.

Best of luck.